# Possible to "split up" images, that are already existing in one container?

Tags: docker, jitsi

I am currently trying to get a jitsi meet instance up on an azure server. My boss wants it to be in a container instance. This means I need (i think) individual images i can upload on the server. The repository looks like this: https://github.com/jitsi/docker-jitsi-meet There are several Dockerfiles in different folders (If you start it in Docker the Container has 4 images)
My question is: Is it possible to split these images up so I can have 4 individual ones? Or is it even the right approach?

I tried just plainly removing the files of every image but one, which didn't work (But to be fair I also didn't expect it to work). Unfortunately I just don't know what else to do

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking here. You can certainly create multiple container iamges from the same directory structure, using a different Dockerfile for each image. There seems to be some documentation around running jitsi in containers [here](https://jitsi.github.io/handbook/docs/devops-guide/devops-guide-docker/).

Comment: I concur the question doesn't really make a lot of sense. Regardless if you find yourself guessing at your boss' intent, why don't you first have a conversation about actual goals and their motivations.

Comment: Adding to other comments, jitsi-meet is a wonderful software. Do not try to "hack" it... It works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I don't know what I did, was probably too tired yesterday after trying to make it work. Don't really know how to explain it.
JitsMeet has 4 Images (Web, prosody, jicofo and jvb) and I had to push the individual images to a container instance. I thought for this to work I had to split up the original File so all images are in separate folders.
Didn't realize that I could just push the images even though they're connected.

So yeah, problem solved i guess :).

Comment: `push the individual images to a container instance` Just to be clear about what's happening with Docker: A "container" is a running instance of an "image". A Docker image has layers (files and metadata zipped up and managed by Docker).

Comment: When you push an image, it goes to a docker repository. When you run an image, it starts a container (or multiple containers).